# How can I call a method in jar from another eclipse plugin project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin

I want to call a method in jar from another eclipse plugin project that has dependent to the project. But eclipse can't resolve the classname in jar.

#### Example:

I created `com.plugin.main` and `com.plugin.sub` project.

- Added poi-ooxml-xxx.jar into `com.plugin.sub` project and added the buildpath through preference dialog.
- Added all packages in jar as exported packages to MANIFEST.MF in `com.plugin.sub project`.
- Added `com.plugin.sub` as required plugin to MANIFEST.MF in com.plugin.main project.

But eclipse can't resolve the classname in jar `WorkbookFactory` from com.plugin.main.actions.SampleAction. Why?

[image: projects info]

#### Information:

- eclipse 3.6(Helios)
- JavaSE-1.7.
- `WorkbookFactory`'s FQCN is `org.apache.poi.ss.user.model.WorkbookFactory`.

MANIFEST.MF in `com.plugin.main`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Main
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.plugin.main; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.plugin.main.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: PLUGIN
Require-Bundle: com.plugin.sub;visibility:=reexport,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

MANIFEST.MF in `com.plugin.sub`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Sub
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.plugin.sub
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.plugin.sub.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: PLUGIN
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Export-Package: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel
Bundle-ClassPath: poi-ooxml-3.8-beta3-20110606.jar,
 .
```

build.properties in `com.plugin.sub`:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               poi-ooxml-3.8-beta3-20110606.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Wrong way of Add jars to project

You can add jars through `Add JARs` button in Library tab in Preference Dialog.

[image]

Then, `.class` file in the project is edited automatically as follows:

```
<classpath>
    ...
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="poi-ooxml-3.8-beta3-20110606.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

But the added tag should has `exported` attribute as follows:

```
<classpath>
    ...
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="poi-ooxml-3.8-beta3-20110606.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

It isn't generated automatically. You have to add the tag in `Order and Export` tab by hand.

### Correct way of Add jars to project

**In eclipse, you shouldn't edit Java Build Path manually.** You should use Plug-in Manifest Editor because `.class` is edited automatically when you edit a data through the editor. And also `build.properties`, `plugin.xml`, `MANIFEST.MF` will be edited correctly and automatically.

When you add jars to the project, you have to use Classpath section in Runtime tabs in Plug-in Manifest Editor. When add jars through the section, `classpathentry` tag with `export` attribute will be added in `.class` file. Not only that, the jar will be added as binary includes in build.properties.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

1. Open the manifest files of both the project in `Manifest Editor`. Go to `Runtime` tab. In the `Class path` section check the entries. Add `.` (means current folder) if not exist. If `.` entry exists then move it on top. Save the editor and check.
2. Right click on `com.plugin.main` project and go to Properties. Go to `Java Build Path`. On right hand side go to `Project` tab. Then add `com.plugin.sub` project.

If adopted point 2 then remember test the application after exporting and running outside eclipse.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried your solution but it wasn't solved. I found the solution myself.